# HTML Table head CSS theming

Tags: html, css, html-table, z-index

I have some CSS theming which I would like to do to the head of a table which the head of the table does not actually support. (great, right?!)

So my idea was to add an element BEHIND the table head and apply the theming to that!

However my attempts to add tables, tbodies, theads, th's, or td's with negative z-indexes have all failed miserably.

On the flip side, I could put my table header in its own table and then encapsulate the table and do the theming on THAT... But then the th's in my header would not be aligned to the td's in my tbody! I can't encapsulate the tbody or td's/tr because divs are not allowed inside tables when not encapsulated by td or tr...

The effects I want to do are:
Set border width and color
Set border radius
Set background-image and color

The border radius is what will not work

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your question how to apply a border-radius to a table head? Can you show us your HTML and CSS and maybe give us a mockup of what you want it to look like?

Comment: Do you want to do it for the th of your table??

Comment: Hi there! could you provide a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) link of what you are trying to do? its a great tool to share your problem with the rest of the community, and it provides a great html css and js editor for us to provide solutions too!

Comment: Basically, if you have a table, any old table, I'd like the top row to appear sort of like this: http://i.imgur.com/2gWH2.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for but you can set CSS for table header using 'th' element.
For eg. try the following implementation,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

td
{
border:1px solid black;
}
thead th
{
border:1px solid green;
}
thead th:first-child
{
border-radius:12px 0px 0px 12px;
}
thead th:last-child
{
border-radius:0px 12px 12px 0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Middlename</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Peter</td>
<td>Griffin</td>
<td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Lois</td>
<td>Griffin</td>
<td>Griffin</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please check the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp).

You can also set border radius using CSS3.

```
border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
```

If cross-browser compatibility is a problem you can use rounded images as background.

Comment: Unfortuantely, I have a row of Th's, and I'd like to set the entire ROW's border and border radius, instead of just each th individually :(

Comment: @Georges Oates Larsen try the above example. Its just an implementation, you can adjust it for your needs.

Comment: It contains css3 please make sure to run in a css3 supported browser :)

Comment: I would replace the `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` part with the equivalent css rules; let's keep content and style separate.

Answer (score 0):

The general trick is to format the end `<th>` cells so that they have rounded edges on only one side. Here's an example for webkit browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Table Head CSS</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
      table{
      border-spacing: 0;
      }
      th.left{
      margin-right: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
      border-width:2px 0 2px 2px;
      border-style: solid;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
      }
      th.middle{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border-width:2px 0 2px 0;
      border-style: solid;      
      }
      th.right{
      margin-left: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
      border-width:2px 2px 2px 0;
      border-style: solid;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='left'>Test</th><th class='middle'>Test 2</th><th class='right'>Test 3</th>
    </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
  </body>
</html>
```